# Installing Axis2 - with error

Tags: tomcat, apache-axis

I tried to install Axis2 on our Tomcat server.
In theory - its easy.
I downloaded axis2.war from here:
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi

I opened Tomcat's Manager, browse the file, than deploy the file.
Its finished without error, great! Now deploy my webservice file.

I tried to open Axis2, but all of its links start with 127.0.0.1, like my PC would be the server! What? Of course, none of these links works, because my PC dosen't have a Tomcat and Axis2 installed.

We tried it on antoher computer - with the same result.
We tried to edit some config files (actually change all 127.0.0.1 references to our Tomcat servers IP) but it didn't helped.

So why we have this strange error?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what is your problem, but I'll explain what is the process to deploy Axis2 inside the tomcat and how to add a service to it.

1. Shutdown the tomcat server if it is running. (shutdown.bat/shutdown.sh inside tomcat/bin)
2. Put the Axis2.war file inside tomcat/webapps directory.
3. Start the tomcat server (startup.bat/startup.sh tomcat/bin)
4. Now there should be a directory named as a Axis2 inside the webapps directory, which is the deployed axis2.
5. Now you should be able to access your Axis2 using http://127.0.0.1:8080/Axis2
6. You can deploy a service using Axis 2 management console or directly to the tomcat/webapps/axis2/web-inf/services directory as a .aar file or simple directory (In correct format)

NOTE: Make sure your port 8080 is not using by any other application when you are starting the tomcat instance. Otherwise change the default port to some other inside web.xml.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. So, there is a Tomcat server, 192.168.0.1. My PC is 192.168.0.152. After I deployed Axis2, the references inside (list services, validation, etc) start with 127.0.0.1, on MY computer. Instead of 192.168.0.1, where Tomcat server is. And of course they are not working, because there is no Axis2 or Tomcat on 127.0.0.1, they are just false references.

Comment: Can you access that machine using it's external ip ? like what happens to 192.168.0.1:8080 from your computer ? and are you using custom wsdl or auto generated one ?

Comment: I don't know it is accessable via externel ip or not, I will ask our sysadmin. On 192.168.0.1:8080 is the Tomcat, and it works properly. And other applications too on this Tomcat. Only Axis2 produces this strange thing. I'm not sure what wsdl u asking?

Comment: I am still not clear about your question. What do you mean by "I tried to open Axis2, but all of its links start with 127.0.0.1"? What are those links ? Have you tried 192.168.0.1:8080/axis2/servces.

Comment: Of course I tried - there is nothing there. Somehow - during the installation - my PC got the 127.0.0.1 address for Axis2. When I see the applications in Tomcat Manager, Axis2 has the address: 192.168.0.1:8080/axis2. BUT! After I clicked on it (inside Axis2) all references show 127.0.0.1:8080/axis2/... that is nonsense, there is nothing there. I cannot write it on another way.

Comment: Can you access the services using 192.168.0.1:8080/axis2/services/listServices url? (By manually typing). If you can, how are urls appear for each axis service after that?

Comment: No, there is nothing on 192.168.0.1:8080/axis2/services/listServices. And also, I cant install any service because Axis2 functions don't working because the wrong url's... My guess is Tomcat somehow screw the path of Axis2...

Comment: Well then I am out of options. Check your web.xml inside axis2/web-inf for any anomalies. Or try to re deploy axis2 using my method without using tomcat manager.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time, I'll try to solve this, because I need a working Axis2 :)